# File created but returns false

Tags: java, android, file, exists, creation

I don't understand why we don't enter in the second if. I first check if the file exists (no, logic), I create it, and I check again but it still returns false. I tried an hour find the problem and I'm sure it's a stupid error. Sorry for my poor english

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.testcreatefileonclick;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Button button;
    Button addTeam;
    Boolean append = true;

    String name = "nomFichier.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        addTeam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        addTeam.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            File fichier = new File(name);


            if (!fichier.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File doesn't exists");
            }


            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(name, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
            osw.write("text");
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();

            //Why don't we go in this if ?
            if (fichier.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File exists");
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Working Code

```
package com.example.testcreatefileonclick;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    Button button;
    Button addTeam;
    Boolean append = true;
    String name = "nomFichier.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        addTeam = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        addTeam.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            String filePath = (this.getFilesDir().getPath().toString());
            File fichier = new File(filePath + name);

            if (!fichier.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File doesn't exists");
            }

            fichier.createNewFile();
            FileWriter file = new FileWriter(filePath + name);
            file.write("text");
            file.flush();
            file.close();

            if (fichier.exists()) {
                System.out.println("File exists");
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: read openFileOutput documentation. it has not the same bahaviour as File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this :

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(name, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
        osw.write("text");
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
```

by this :

```
fichier.createNewFile();
FileWriter file = new FileWriter(name);
file.write("text");
file.flush();
file.close();
```

Comment: I tried and I get this error: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Comment: That's because you can't write wherever you want on your device.
You have to write the file in your application folder.
Check this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787942/android-read-only-file-system-ioexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787942/android-read-only-file-system-ioexception)

Comment: Ok thank's my code works now. I put my new code in my post to help other people.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Why don't we go in this if ?
```

The most likely reason (IMO) is that `openFileOutput(name, MODE_WORLD_READABLE)` throws an exception.

If that happens, you won't know about it because of this appalling piece of code.

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Why appalling?

1. You are catching `Exception` rather than the specific exceptions that you *expect* to be thrown (e.g. `IOException`).
2. You are "squashing" the exception.  You are catching it and *silently* throwing it away.

Each of those things individually is *bad practice*.  Doing them together is ... well ... you *deserve* to have wasted an hour on this!

---

If my diagnosis of a squashed exception is incorrect, then there's another possibility.  The docs for `openFileOutput` say:

> *"Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing."*.

It is not entirely clear where that file would be opened / created, but it is plausible that it is in a different "place" to where `File.exists` is looking.  You will notice that `openFileOutput` does NOT take a `File` object as its output.

---

Finally, there is also a more subtle problem, that won't hurt you in this context, but *could* in others.  You wrote ...

```
        if (!fichier.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exists");
        }
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(name, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

The problem with this is that there is a race condition.  In between calling `exists` and calling `openFileOutput`, there is a small time window in which some other application could leap in and create the file.  So when you then call `openFileOutput`, it might discover that the file has already been created.

Clearly, in this case it makes no difference.  But in other cases it might.  The lesson is that calling `File.exists()`, `File.canWrite` and so on to "guard" a following attempt to create / open a file is not reliable.

Comment: I checked and no Exception is catching.

Comment: Well I stand by my commentary.  Even if this isn't the true cause of your problem, it is terrible code and should be fixed.

Comment: Added another possible diagnosis

Answer (score 0):

If not the exception issue below, it may be caching the result from your first call to the exists method (unlikely).  You could try creating a new file object after the call to test this.

If I woas you I would be using the createNewFile method, which will return a boolean for you to use in your logic.  This would be better than having to ask IO twice if it exists.

```
public boolean createNewFile() throws IOException
```